# Parabola and Differentiation

Tags: derivatives

Let P(not equal O) be a point on the parabola y= x^2 and Q be the point where the perpendicular bisector of OP intersects the y-axis. As P approaches the origin O along the parabola, does Q have a limiting position? If so, find it.

So i differentiate y and get 2x. when something intersects the y -axis then x is zero. how do i find the limiting position? im not very sure what are they asking for in the question. need help... thank you..

Comment: Draw a picture. What happens to the point $Q$ when $P$ approaches the origin?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ have coordinates $(t,t^2)$. The gradient of $OP$ is $t$, so the equation of the perpendicular bisector of $OP$ is $$y-\frac{t^2}{2}=-\frac 1t(x-\frac t2)$$
Therefore $Q$ has $y$ coordinate $$\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac 12\rightarrow\frac 12$$ as $t\rightarrow0$

Comment: the gradient is not 1/2t? dont have to differentiate?

Comment: No the gradient of the graph is not directly relevant here, its is the gradient of OP and the line perpendicular to it.